# Split last two hours in 10 minutes slices

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar

I am trying to get every 10 minutes of the last hour.

For example, now is 15:46:41

I want [15:40:00, 15:30:00, 15:20:00, 15:10:00, 15:00:00, 14:50:00, 14:40:00, 14:30:00, 14:20:00, 14:10:00, 14:00:00, 13:50:00, 13:40:00]

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let now = Date()
var components = DateComponents()
components.hour = -2
if let early = calendar.date(byAdding: components, to: now) {
    let nowMin = calendar.component(.minute, from: early)
    let diff = 10 - (nowMin % 10)
    components.minute = diff
    var minutes: [Int] = []
    for _ in 0...13 {
        // I cant figure out what should I do next.
    }
    print(minutes)
}
```

Comment: If now is `15:46:41` then 10 minutes back should it not be `15:36:41`?

Comment: Hmm sorry about my English, I want nearest. Every 10,20,30.... minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get now's minute, get the remainder of this value divided by ten and subtract it from that value. This way you get the last tenth hour minute, then you just need to set it with the same hour component to now to find out the first element of your array. Next you can fill the rest of dates subtracting 10 minutes times the element position from the start date. Try like this:

**Xcode 11 • Swift 5.1** (for older versions just add the return statement as usual)

```
extension Date {
    var hour: Int { Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: self) }
    var minute: Int { Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: self) }
    var previousHourTenth: Date { Calendar.current.date(bySettingHour: hour, minute: minute - minute % 10, second: 0, of: self)! }
    func lastNthHourTenth(n: Int) -> [Date] { (0..<n).map {  Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: -10*$0, to: previousHourTenth)! } }
}
```

---

Playground testing

```
Date()                          // "Sep 25, 2019 at 10:19 AM"
Date().previousHourTenth        // "Sep 25, 2019 at 10:10 AM"
Date().lastNthHourTenth(n: 13)  // "Sep 25, 2019 at 10:10 AM", "Sep 25, 2019 at 10:00 AM", "Sep 25, 2019 at 9:50 AM", "Sep 25, 2019 at 9:40 AM", "Sep 25, 2019 at 9:30 AM", "Sep 25, 2019 at 9:20 AM", "Sep 25, 2019 at 9:10 AM", "Sep 25, 2019 at 9:00 AM", "Sep 25, 2019 at 8:50 AM", "Sep 25, 2019 at 8:40 AM", "Sep 25, 2019 at 8:30 AM", "Sep 25, 2019 at 8:20 AM", "Sep 25, 2019 at 8:10 AM"]
```

Now you just need to use DateFormatter to display those dates as needed to the user.